# In Office web add-in, how can I know if automatic saving is enabled?

Tags: office365, office-js

I am building a web add-in for Microsoft Word ; it will be used in Word online (Office 365) or in local Word.

I integrated my web app with Office online, the documents are automatically saved in my server.

But if a user downloads the document and edit the file in his computer, it's not automatically saved. So I added a button in my add-in to save the document in the server.

I don't want this button to appear in Office online because it's automatically saved, how can I know if the document is in a context where doc is automatically saved ?

I've seen there is a "_host_Info" parameter in the request, but I'm not sure it's a good idea to use this - because I don't know all the available values (and which ones support automatic save), or if new values will appear later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property specifically to check if auto-save is on/off. This is actually an interesting request make sure to voice it/vote for an existing one in our user voice channel https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word

That said, you have an alternative you can use to infer this. there is a last save timestamp document property you can get. (use property "lastSaveTime") you can use this value against the time you last saved the document.

here is a Gist you can use in the [scriptlab add-in](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380862&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false)  with a code sample on how to get document properties..
https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/a9155f0af862e19edf8b119c53d05d52

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: I'm going to look at this, it may help me. In fact, after having thought about this, what I really need to know is whether the file is opened using the WOPI protocol or not - because my "save" button is made to replace the WOPI saving.

Comment: that's not possible.